# At what point container creates request and response object?

Tags: java, servlets

When the client request comes, the container finds the correct servlet based on the URL and creates a pair of request and response objects.

According to me, the request and response objects only get created if the container finds valid servlet. That is, if there is no valid servlet found for the requested URL, then request and response objects don't get created.

However, I am not sure of this. Can anyone please confirm.

Comment: Request object is created when you make request like in browser or restful call. Your servlet tries to read that request, and if it understands, then process accordingly like finding proper url, or creating other type of objects. Once the request is received, response will be created by container wether it can process the request or not, at worse case, it would be error in response. That's what I THINK.

Comment: Most containers use a pool pattern for this, and get unused `Request`/`Response` objects from a pool and populate them - so strictly speaking the container creates the objects at some time around startup/first request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In chapter **12.1 Use of URL paths**, the [Servlet Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) states

> The path used for mapping to a servlet is the request URL from the
>   request object minus the context path and the path parameters.

We can therefore assume that the request object (and possibly the response object) are created before any mapping logic is executed.

Note also that

> Containers commonly recycle request objects in order to avoid the
>   performance overhead of request object creation.